# a single word for someone reliable, who is located where you want something done, and you trust them to do whatever it is for you

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word or a catchy phrase for such person. 
The best I could think of is 'concierge', but it's not good, as it's a complicated word, and not personable. 
Someone you could fully trust, that cares about quality of job they do for you (even if it's just an errand sometimes), promptly, as if you did it yourself, even better.

thank you!

Comment: A "go-to" person, perhaps?

Comment: I'm thinking "miracle".

Comment: Something like a _[factotum](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/factotum) [ex machina](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deus+ex+machina) of the year_? A [jack of all trades](http://www.freethesaurus.com/Jack+of+all+trades) perhaps?

Comment: @HotLicks "The impossible, we do straight away. Miracles take a little longer." Rather like this site, really.

Answer (score 1):

A secret keeper, or one you can tell things in confidence, is a **confidant**, although this doesn't imply them doing a good job of things you ask of them.

As suggested by Mick in the comments, you could delegate tasks to your **go-to-guy** or **go-to-girl** or **go-to-person**.

Last one: your **right-hand man** or **right-hand woman** is your trusted helper. It implies similar things to "go-to", but typically is a more personable relationship, which is why I think it may be the best of these three.

Comment: I like your last suggestion best. Was just going to type it in myself. You an rely on your right-hand man/woman for absolutely anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about *alter ego*?

The Free Dictionary:

> [*alter ego*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alter+ego): a perfect
>   substitute or deputy; a very close and trusted friend who seems almost
>   a part of yourself

If you're lucky enough to have this kind of *alter ego*, you have someone you can fully trust, who cares about the quality of job they do for you (even if it's just an errand sometimes), and who does it as promptly as you would do it. It's as if you did it yourself, only better.

Comment: Interesting that someone disliked this enough to downvote it -- not merely to not vote, but to downvote. It seems like a rather good answer to me.

Comment: Sounds OK to me, Richard, I've just put it back up!

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks. I was mainly trying to understand the objection, which is hard to do without feedback.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I've never heard or seen alter ego used in this sense, which may be why one would be opposed? Typically when I read "alter ego" I think of an alternate personality (eg. Peter Parker's alter-ego is Spiderman).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***(man/girl) Friday***!

TFD:

> **[man Friday](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/man+Friday)**
>   *n*. *pl. men Friday or men Fridays*
>
> An efficient, faithful male aide or employee.
>   [After Friday, a
>   character in Robinson Crusoe, a novel by Daniel Defoe.]
>
> American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.
>   Copyright © 2016 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.
>   Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> **[girl Friday](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/girl+Friday)**
>   *n*. *Informal*
>
> An efficient and faithful woman aide or employee.
>   [girl + (man)
>   Friday.]
>
> American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.
>   Copyright © 2016 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.
>   Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights
>   reserved.

Wikipedia:

> **[Friday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(Robinson_Crusoe))** is one of the main characters of Daniel Defoe's 1719 novel
>   Robinson Crusoe. Robinson Crusoe names the man, with whom he cannot at
>   first communicate, Friday because they first meet on that day. The
>   character is the source of the expression "**Man Friday**", used to
>   describe a male personal assistant or servant, especially one who is
>   particularly competent or loyal. Current usage also includes "**Girl
>   Friday**".
>
> The term **[Man Friday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(Robinson_Crusoe)#Idiom)** has become an idiom, still in mainstream
>   usage, to describe an especially faithful servant or
>   one's best servant or right-hand man. The female equivalent is **Girl
>   Friday**.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could say a lifeline, though it may sound like "Who Wants to be a Millionaire".

> If I don't know how to do something, Wiki-How is my lifeline.

Or

> Sarah is my lifeline for free things from Gap.

Maybe...

> "What is the definition of **lifeline**?"
>   "Um...I don't know! I'll go with my lifeline!"